# Field whose group of units is finitely generated

Tags: ring-theory, field-theory, abelian-groups, finitely-generated

Let $k$ be a field such that its group of units $k^\times$ is finitely generated ; then is it true that $k$ is finite ? I can only show that $\text{char}(k) >0$ . Please help . Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such a field would be a quotient of $R=\Bbb Z[X_1,\ldots,X_n]$.
It is fairly well-known that all quotient fields of $R$ are finite.
If you know the characteristic is $p$, then such a field is a quotient
of $\Bbb F_p[X_1,\ldots,X_n]$ and so by the Nullstellensatz is a finite
extension of $\Bbb F_p$.

(I omit the proof that the characteristic in nonzero; that is another
application of the Nullstellensatz.)

Comment: I can understand that $k^\times$ will be a homomorphic image of the additive group of $\mathbb Z[X_1,...,x_n]$ ; but why the field $k$ itself should be a homomorphic image ? And consequently because of this I cannot understand why should the subsequent argument work

Comment: Take a finite  set of generators of $k^\times$ and their **reciprocals** and choose enough $X_i$ to map onto all of them. @users

Comment: Do you need nullstellensatz to show that the characteristic is positive? You can say that if $K$ has char 0, then $K^\times$ cannot be finitely generated because it contains the infinitely generated abelian group $\mathbb{Q}^\times$.